# MS SQL Server 2014 license reusability

Tags: licensing, sql-server-2014

I have a MS SQL Server 2014 Standard license in my server.
I need to restore a database in a different secondary machine to get data of a particular table from a backup.

The problem is that this table is stored in a database of more than 10GB and I cannot use a SQL Express license due its size limitations.
I thought to use the same license of the main server for few minutes and then uninstall the server in the secondary machine. (I know that Microsoft and Jesus don't want me to do this, but I cannot buy another license to restore a table!)

My question is, can I do this without troubles in the main server? The license duplication (for few minutes) can stop the main server?

Comment: You should be able to restore from backup, with a different database name, on the same machine. Use the Restore Database wizard in SSMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Licenses are not really checked with each other. They are legal - there is no technical non duplicity check. Particularly because it is also allowed to have a machine "ready to take over" (cold spare) that you only occasionally start to patch it.

So, nothing stops you.

But you also do not need to. Just grab a 180 day trial ;) Or use the Developer Version.

Comment: Maybe Developer Version is the best choice, I did not know about this version.